# How to add default implementation using generic protocol extension?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I want to add default implementation for Int/Float/Double value.

```swift
protocol ValueLimit {
    associatedtype T where T: Comparable

    func limit(from minValue: T, to maxValue: T) -> T
}

extension ValueLimit {
    func limit(from minValue: T, to maxValue: T) -> T {
        return Swift.max(Swift.min(self as! Self.T, maxValue), minValue)
    }
}

extension Int: ValueLimit {
    typealias T = Int
}

extension Float: ValueLimit {
    typealias T = Float
}

extension Double: ValueLimit {
    typealias T = Double
}
```

I belive there is a better way, which can simply use empty extension `extension Int: ValueLimit {}` to do this, without `typealias T = Int`, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would be simpler.

```swift
extension Comparable {
    func limit(from minValue: Self, to maxValue: Self) -> Self {
        return Swift.max(Swift.min(self, maxValue), minValue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for an associated type, you can simply use `Self` in your `limit` declaration. You can also declare that conforming types need to conform to `Comparable` as well in the protocol declaration.

`Self` refers to the current type, so when using it in protocol methods, it refers to the conforming type. This is how standard library protocols such as `Equatable` and `Comparable` are implemented as well.

```
protocol ValueLimit: Comparable {
    func limit(from minValue: Self, to maxValue: Self) -> Self
}

extension ValueLimit {
    func limit(from minValue: Self, to maxValue: Self) -> Self {
        Swift.max(Swift.min(self, maxValue), minValue)
    }
}

extension Int: ValueLimit {}

extension Float: ValueLimit {}

extension Double: ValueLimit {}
```